# SVG linearGradient with animation keyframes together

Tags: css, svg

I create simple example where use two path `sec1` and `sec2`. For both path I use `linearGradient` with id `step1` and `step2`. First part (`sec1`) work great, second part (`sec2`) not yet.

`Sec2` must first be in hide, then change positions and scale. I try do this by keyframing, but can't hide `sec2` in beginning. Also if I try to use in `linearGradient` attribute `begin="step1.end;"` it not working, and not running after filling `sec1`.

I want create like one animation line which begin from left to right and then from top to bottom, with first change `sec2` postion and scale (in hide) after this begin drawing and show gradient animation.

My example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/0gkrch42/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had two main problems...

1. Your second animation didn't start hidden because you had the gradient offset starting at "40%' instead of zero
2. The second problem was that when you use `id.end` for timing attributes, the `id` has to reference another `<animation>` element, not a graphics element.

```html
<svg id="Logo-Defs" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="step1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0">
      <stop offset="40%" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="black">
        <animate attributeName="offset" values="0;1" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" dur="5s" begin="0s" />
      </stop>
      <stop offset="40%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="black">
        <animate id="anim1" attributeName="offset" values="0;1" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" dur="5s" begin="0s" />
      </stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="step2" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="black">
        <animate attributeName="offset" values="0;1" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" dur="5s" begin="anim1.end;" />
      </stop>
      <stop offset="0%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="black">
        <animate attributeName="offset" values="0;1" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" dur="5s" begin="anim1.end;" />
      </stop>
    </linearGradient>

<g>
      <path id="sec1" class="cls-1" d="M155.06,43V41.83A42.78,42.78,0,0,0,143.12,16.5c-10.62-11.07-26-12-26-12S10.86,5,3.3,5C3.27,5,.44.25.44.25L117.08.73C137,2,158,18.38,159.07,43,158.09,43,156.08,43,155.06,43Z" />
      <path id="sec2" class="cls-1" d="M159.22,129.83V43.18h-4.06q.11,43.42.22,86.84,0,1.89,0,3.78v.91h3.82Z" />
    </g>
    
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg id="svg" class="Animate-Path" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 512 650" xml:space="preserve">

  <use id="Draw-sec1" xlink:href="#sec1" fill="url(#step1)" />
  <use id="Draw-sec2" xlink:href="#sec2" fill="url(#step2)" />

  <!--<use class="Animate-Fill" xlink:href="#Logo-Group" /> -->
</svg>
```

Comment: One small question why this not work in FF (I mean someAction keyframes) ? Thank you!

Comment: @Brotheryura The CSS animation wasn't needed here. I've removed it.